# How to create and use database in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm trying to create and use a database but I'm struggling with implementing it.

I have a separate file for the database that should handle all logic.
I saved the SQL queries in variables.

The problem i have is, that when the database isn't created yet i can't connect with the database property. I can create the database, but if i continue and try to create a table it won't create it. The query is successful but it won't show in phpmyadmin

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

const host = "localhost";
const user = "root";
const password = "";
let database = "floweraufdauer";

const createDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS floweraufdauer;";
const createUserTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users \
                        ( \
                            id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, \
                            username varchar(255) NOT NULL \
                            firstname varchar(255) NULL, \
                            lastname varchar(255) NULL, \
                            role ENUM('admin', 'user', 'manager', 'etc') NOT NULL, \
                            authToken varchar(255) NULL \
                        );"

const createSuperUser = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users (id, username, role) values (1, 'admin', 'admin);"


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err){
        console.log("Keine verbindung zur Datenbank");
    }else console.log("Connected!");
  });

function query(sql, name){
    connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Create ", name);
        }else{
            console.log(name, " => Result: ", result);
        }
    })
}

function initDatabase(){
    query(createDatabase, "Create Database");
    // Use not working
    // query("USE floweraufdauer", "User database floweraufdauer")
    query(createUserTable, "Create Usertable");
    query(createSuperUser, "Add Superuser");
}

initDatabase();

// module.exports = {
//     connection: connection
// }
```

Comment: Please tag with database platform. Generally, not a good idea to create a database on-the-fly.  When you create the database manually, and then say "try to create a table it won't create it." what does that mean?  Error?

Comment: using root user is abit dodgy, your dbs should really be in place already or if your making a plugin type system, which then you should create an install/uninstall method which is called for the db install/uninstall of the plugin, doing every table on boot seems inefficient. there is lots of libs that can handle migrations too, but if you simply want to dynamically add things as you go along you can use something like an orm [*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autorm), then you don't need to create the table it will do it for you.

Comment: Ok so the best would be to create the database before i do anything else?

Comment: Exactly! You should have created tables before writing queries. It is recommended method, that way you will be sure the data will be inserted into already created table.